# MYSQL or PostgresSQL on AWS

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I am trying to understand the trade-offs between going with MySQL or PostgreSQL on AWS.

Some considerations for me are that I am an amateur database user, so I need to be sure resources are available which allow me to overcome problems quickly. Along these lines, I bought the book 'PostgreSQL on the Cloud' and was all set to go with PostgreSQL since the book laid out a great use case.

One thing held me back though is that it is important for my work to be able to to easily use Excel as a front end for importing and exporting data into and out of the Database on AWS.

It looks like MySQL has an open extension which is fully integrated with Excel and is also well documented. My research into PostgreSQL uncovered a much more uneven integration with Excel and a lot of long painful group frustration a closer integration has not already occurred.

Right now, I am leaning to MySQL, but want to make sure I am not missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: Well you can export a table to CSV easily enough with either tool.  Actually, I think most people would consider MySQL more user friendly than Postgres, at least with regards to the features both do support.

Comment: Yes, exporting is cool and I don't have a problem with that. I am looking for a more dynamic approach.where I can really rely on Excel to push and pull to the database. For instance,.I plan to set up forms in Excel and will look to push the data entered to the database.

Comment: I would recommend then going from Excel via a CSV or other delimited file, because this is the type of file which is easy to import into a database table.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft touts a PostgreSQL plugin as well: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-a-postgresql-database-power-query-bf941e52-066f-4911-a41f-2493c39e69e4. Never used it, so can't comment on it.

You mention you are a beginner, so I'll add... be careful about security with either of these options. There are options to encrypt the channel between the client and server, which you indicate is running on AWS. If not secure, anyone would be able to effectively monitor the connections, extract credentials, and do whatever to your AWS-hosted DB. Generally, cloud-hosted DBs should be behind an authentication/authorization login process.

Comment: Thank you! Security is important. Yes, I found this addin from Microsoft. A bit more digging however is what left me concerned that technically it was not really a good solution for me. What options do you like for security?